# how spark reads data when we are using a filter in where

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm reading a key from a table which is huge in size (900 GB). 
its just one where condition but spark has launched many jobs with huge no of tasks.

i'm using 11 node cluster (128 GB memory and 16 cores per node)

i know that we may need more number of tasks, but why those many jobs, why cant it process in a single stage...?

Can someone please explain what happens internally when we use a where condition..

Appreciate your response.[please check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPfc1.jpg)

Comment: What is `sample.table_a`?

Comment: From that table only reading .. it has 900GB

Comment: What kind of table it is? A Spark view, a SQL database table, a Cassandra table...? Spark tries to push predicates to the connector if supported.

Comment: Spark sql table. Data bricks delta (parquet)

Answer (score 0):

Spark is for bulk processing, not a single key lookup as your image shows as in, say, an ORACLE database, with an index. For a JOIN for many rows these lookups are finer, of course.

Spark does not know what you are doing (semantically), so it follows its distributed model and processes in parallel - meaning many tasks - for many partitions.

The image is not a proper use case for Spark.